# How to read .vid files in android

Tags: android, file, video

So I am able to get all the video files from the android device but I am not able to get **.vid** files I tried to get some lead about the .vid file in google but no such lead I am only able to retrieve the following file through MXPlayer only. Any idea on how to retrieve the following data will be helpful I am using standard MediaStore class to get data.
hex value via https://www.onlinehexeditor.com/

```
74 c9 94 44 f2 23 a9 f0 da db 79 0b 0c 11 ec 08 
5e 06 6e 68 9b 8c 9e 66 5f c4 04 a2 0b 83 0c e7 
05 a8 89 54 5c 94 44 be 6c 81 17 98 7c e9 a4 b7 
61 4b e2 6f 28 6f 56 18 49 25 0a 90 3b 24 3e 39 
92 a5 d1 32 93 2d 19 0d 3c bf 65 07 0f 8a 11 73 
b5 99 4e b1 12 c5 96 b2 f1 03 65 5a ae 18 b1 b5 
72 42 34 f7 43 ac 2d 94 30 df e6 dc d3 87 eb 96 
ea 36 39 c4 ed 6b 0e ed 42 d3 49 c5 2a f0 00 2d 
6d 98 e2 7f d3 ae 9d af ba ba ac 24 af ce 15 b9 
fe 6b ac 0c e2 71 ab 10 90 bc e5 94 ac 2a 85 8e 
df 0d 0f 9e 1f 33 c5 9e 6e 5c b7 ef 3b dd 8b 30 
49 70 9a dd ab 78 22 e8 f8 90 10 f3 3b 8f 23 a3
```

Comment: `.vid` is a container. You need to find out the actual video codec used. Maybe paste the first 64 bytes (or more) of the file into your question. You can copy the bytes values from a hex editor (get a free one or use an online hex viewer).

Comment: ok thx i will update the question@VC.One

Comment: Are these the **beginning** bytes? They are not matching any popular video format. Does MXPlayer have some option to inspect the audio/video types when you play the video there?

Comment: ya its showing MPEG-4  encoding lavf56.40.101 dont know much how this will help you

Comment: Hmm. Well an MP4 should start with bytes `00 00 00 18 66 74 79 70 6D 70 34 32 00 00 00 00` which basically says `ftypmp42` or in human speak _"this file type is MP4"_. Anyways... **(1)** It's also possible for the header to be at the back of the file. Maybe MX Player is scanning all bytes and later finding the header (which is always needed by the decoder to play the video correctly). **(2)** If it's a silent video, those bytes could also just be the video codec part (H264) only, but with MX player still labeling it as MPEG-4.

Comment: PS: Search your file for these bytes `6D 6F 6F 76` (use a desktop hex editor if possible). Those bytes are the beginning of the metadata (header) that the decoder needs to play this video correctly. If your OS is Windows then I recommend [HxD Editor](https://mh-nexus.de/en/downloads.php?product=HxD20) for bytes viewing.